# Adding inward facing triangles on a polyline/polygon SLD Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, sld

How do I create inward facing triangles on a polygon/polyline such as below in Geoserver SLD?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Graphic Stroke](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/lines.html#railroad-hatching) with a [triangle shape](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#shape-symbols)

```
  <LineSymbolizer>
     <Stroke>
       <GraphicStroke>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>extshape://triangle</WellKnownName>
             <Stroke>
               <CssParameter name="stroke">#333333</CssParameter>
               <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
             </Stroke>
           </Mark>
           <Size>12</Size>
         </Graphic>
       </GraphicStroke>
     </Stroke>
   </LineSymbolizer>
```

Comment: Thats brilliant iant, thank you so much for your helpful reply.

Comment: Wellknownname extshape://triangle does not seem to work for me. Do I have to install some GeoServer Extension?